# Full copy OS drive via network

Tags: robocopy

I want to use Robocopy to copy entire "C:" drive from one machine to another. problem is that on this machine there are many files that are opened by other processes since this is the OS drive.

how can I tell Robocopy to copy the entire drive and write to log what files was not copied?

Comment: Tjis sounds like an X-Y problem.  X is "I want to copy my entire drive". Y is "In this way which is unsuited to do so". Rather than ask "How can I force/workaround the limits of Y" ask a "How can I do X?".  (Hint1:: Simply not copy with the OS running. Hint2: Boot from something else. Hint3: Plenty of answer on the site for those questions).

Comment: Also, you tagged it "backup'. making a backup is different from making a copy and has different answers. Please clarify in your post.  (hint from most backups: Shadowcopies).

Comment: @Hennes 1. I want the copy process to run when I'm not near the machine and the OS holds files in different places in the path. 2. I cant boot the source machine from something else 3. couldn't find answer to my scenario. 4. removed the "backup" tag